# Android 13 permissions won't allow app to overwrite its own files

Tags: linux, permissions, android, file-permissions

I have updated my app to use Android 13 (API 33) permissions. These are different in that there seems to be no explicit "write" permission to external storage:

```
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
```

The old permissions scheme is ignored in API 33:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

The new permissions scheme allows me to ***read*** files created by my own app in external storage (in the DCIM directory). The problem I face is that my app created the directory on external storage using the old permissions scheme, but now my app can't *overwrite the very same files that it wrote* when using the File API as I could before.
This is a huge problem as the app uses its own images file browser, and the user can't delete files within the app that were written before the update. In fact, if I write new images, then clear the app's data or reinstall the app, *I again lose the ability to delete my own files.*
I can't believe this is the intended behavior. However, with no specific write permission anymore for external storage, how do I get permission to delete my own files?

Comment: So you are doing: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#media but not clear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#create-storage-management-activity

Comment: If you can create files you can delete them. You did not tell hiw and when you created them.

Comment: @blackapps Correct, but if I go to the app's info screen and delete storage (which resets the app), I can't delete any files created up to that point. It's is if the device "forgets" which files I created and just denies all attempts to delete files created prior to the app storage reset.

Comment: Yes indeed. The files are there but they dont belong to the app anymore. Only with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE they are available. Or you can select them with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: @blackapps I can try MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but from what I understand Google is strict about letting you get away with this. I can at least see if it fixes the problem in the debugging phase.