# Is there any place on Android to store files persistent?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm using `Application.persistentDataPath` to store game progress data. User can use *Clear data and cache* via app menu and lose progress.

Is there any place to store files persistent? (Cannot be removed by Clear data and cache via App Settings).

If there is no way to save data internally please share a legal ideas to solve a problem.

Comment: If user clear data via app settings all the data from app or game is wipe out. U can save the progress to remote server and fetch it later or you could use google play games plugin [check it here](https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/unity/unity-start)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757732/android-13-permissions-wont-allow-app-to-overwrite-its-own-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an application tag [hasFragileUserData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#hasFragileUserData) added in Android 10.

But I think you should consider using [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) instead.

Comment: is data will be saved on Google Play Games Services if user decide to skip using the service?